# Validating the postgres upgrade using logical replication

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-10

Currently I am trying to upgrade my postgres 9.1 to 10 using logical replication. As 9.1 does not support native logical_replication, I tried slony and made a replica successfully.

P.S. The above replica I created is using a sample dump from an year ago which is only of 800mb.

Now I have few questions.

1. How can I validate whether the replica has all the data replicated successfully. Few suggested to put the master on maintenance mode(few downtime) and do a last N items comparison with both the database on all the tables.
2. I tried with 800mb. Will there be any problem when I go and try with 100+ GB?

Please share your personal experience here. I have been trying to document what are the things that could go wrong so I can always try to anticipate the next course of action.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Data Validator that is shipped with trial version of EDB Postgres Replication server for validating the data between old and new PostgreSQL databases.

You may read the details of Data Validator at [Data Validator Document](https://www.enterprisedb.com/edb-docs/d/edb-postgres-replication-server/user-guides/user-guide/6.2/EDB_Postgres_Replication_Server_Users_Guide.1.62.html)

To download the EDB Replication Server please follow this link: [EDB Replication Server](https://www.enterprisedb.com/enterprise-postgres/edb-postgres-replication-server)

Disclosure: I work for EnterpriseDB (EDB)